# How to show result of SQLite3 query on Php and save it

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm new in SQLite3 and Php7. I'm building a website for studies and at the time of implementing the logic of login with the db sqlite I block: I can not see the result of a query performed .. in a few words when I ask the db to show the pwd of a specific user, I can not see the pwd and consequently to perform all the checks for the login.

Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sql = "select * from user where username = '". $_POST['inuser'] ."'";

    $result = $db --> exec($sql);

    if ($result --> num_rows == 1) {
                $row = $result --> fetch_assoc(); // mi blocca questo fetch_assoc
                $pwd = $row["password"];

                if (trim($_POST['inpassword']) == trim($pwd)) {
                    $_SESSION["isLogged"] = true; 
                    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST['inuser'];
                } else {
                    # pwd errata
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-warning' role='alert'>
                     user/passwrod errati!
                </div>";
                }


            }
    }
```

Comment: In English, please. (As a side note, "ed" is used only if the next word starts with 'e' :P)

Comment: Also `$db --> exec($sql)` this doesn't make sense. I think you meant `$db -> exec($sql)`, `if ($result -> num_rows == 1)` and `$result -> fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Finally, you're open to [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: If I use -> and not --> I have an error

Comment: Ok, what error? I'm in Italy too, but I can't see your screen from here.

Comment: an example:    $db --> exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (id_u int PRIMARY KEY,
                username varchar(50),
                email varchar NOT NULL(50),
                password varchar NOT NULL(25),
                age int');

Comment: error: Warning: SQLite3::exec(): near "(": syntax error in C:\xampp\htdocs\luca\dinamico\header.php on line 57

Comment: In your example query you haven't closed the parentheses at the end (after `age int`). Also `email` should be defined as `email varchar(50) NOT NULL` (`varchar(50)` is the type, not `varchar not null(50)`) and so should `password`

Comment: $db = new SQLite3('db.db');

 if ($db) {
  echo'Connection Successfly!'.'<br>';
 } else {
  echo 'Connection Error'.'<br>';
 }
 


 $sql = $db -> exec('select * from user');
 echo $sql.'<br>'; // output 1

Comment: How I can get the value of my db and store it in php7 variables?

Comment: The [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php) has examples. If there's something that's not clear in there please ask again.

Comment: Thanks , I have resolved my problem now